# How to get the circumference, area and radius of a circle in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the radius, circumference and area of a circle, and it is not working. I'm a complete beginner at java and coding so thank you for the help.

```
public class program54c {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        double  pi = 3.14159; 
        double radius = 15.337;
        double circumference = (2*pi*radius);
        double area = (pi*(radius*2));
        System.out.println("The radius of the circle" = radius);
        System.out.println("The circumference of the circle" = circumference);
        System.out.println("The area of the circle" = area);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: When you have a problem that you need help with, please tell us what you think the code should do (or what you want it to do) _and_ what it actually does. That way we can help you understand how to make it do that. Your question is just too general as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems correct except for one thing (assuming you know your mathematical calculations).

```
System.out.println("The radius of the circle" = radius);
```

**You are not using the correct string concatenation for your output.**

Replace `=` with `+` and try. For example,

```
System.out.println("The radius of the circle " + radius);
```

Comment: There is another error,  `area` should be equals to `pi * radius * radius` instead of `pi * radius * 2`.

Comment: I have left it to the OP to correct as it is OP's business logic, I just wanted to point OP to the syntax error.

Comment: Funny, I thought it was a second syntax error ! OP might tried to square `radius` with `* 2`... We will never know =)

Answer (score 2):

In your print statements, you need to use the `+` operator instead of `=` to append the variables value to your string. For example

```
"The area of the circle " = area
```

should be

```
"The area of the circle " + area
```

this will concatenate (append) the value of `area` to the string `"The area of the circle "`

Full example below:

```
public class program54c
{
    public static void main (String args[])   
    {
        double  pi = 3.14159; 
        double radius = 15.337;
        double circumference = (2*pi*radius);
        double area = (pi*(radius*2));
        System.out.println("The radius of the circle " + radius);
        System.out.println("The circumference of the circle  + circumference);
        System.out.println("The area of the circle " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much- I'm pretty new to this, sorry if my question was general. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I spot two errors in your code:

- The string concatenation, as precised in the others answers, must be done with `+` and not `=`.
- `radius * 2` is not radius² ! You should use `Math.pow(radius, 2)` or `radius*radius`.

On a side note, you can use `Math.PI` instead of your own `pi`.